# How to stop incorrect value in datepicker when previous data select in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-ui-datepicker

Here, I got code for disable date in datepicker. when user select previous date then it alert to put a valid future date. It's working.
But It's printing whatever we select previous date. **I want to stop print when previous date select.** Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="col-md-8">
   <input class="form-control datepicker" id="datepicker" onchange="checkDate()" required type="date" name="smexdate" value="<?=$promotion_details['expiry_date']?>" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
</div>
```

and JavaScript below.

```
function checkDate() {
var selectedText = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
var selectedDate = new Date(selectedText);
var now = new Date();
 if (selectedDate < now)
  {
   alert("Date must be in the future");
  return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Take care to correctly spell JavaScript to avoid search collisions with Java. [JavaScript](http://javascriptisnotjava.io)

Answer (score 0):

**How about this?**

```
    var lastData;

    function checkDate() {
        var selectedText = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;

        var selectedField = document.getElementById('datepicker');

        var selectedDate = new Date(selectedText);
        var now = new Date();

        if (selectedDate < now)
        {
            console.log(lastData)
            selectedField.value = (lastData) ? lastData : '';
            alert("Date must be in the future");
            return 0;
        }
        var theDate = new Date(selectedText);
        var month = theDate.getMonth() + 1;
        var date = theDate.getDate();
        var year = theDate.getFullYear();

        lastData = year + "-" + String("0" + month).slice(-2) + "-" + String("0" + date).slice(-2);
    }
```